# Capture video viewing

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can anyone point me in a right direction - I need to capture information on who, when opens which video (uploaded to particular SP site and list) and if the video watched to the end (I think there should flow be involved, maybe some javascript as well ).
Then I need to pop this data into Azure SQL database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, the only option will be using [audit log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide). As a file stored in SharePoint Library, we can find the log of viewing the audio however not being able to know if it is watched to the end.  And For videos, it may be better to use Stream to handle as there are a lot of file types not supported to be opened in browser. SharePoint is not able to handle more video analytics.

[Microsoft Stream enhanced analytics for videos](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=Microsoft%20Stream) is still in development.